# Drupal content shown an all domains "Domain Access" Module

Tags: drupal

In Drupal "Domain Access Module" Content is added for a specific domain using "Domain access options".

"Send to all affiliates" option is Unchecked & in "Publish to" Option specific domain is selected but content is shown on all domains, Instead of showing content only on selected domain & Displaying 404 error on all other domains.

Any Solution for above problem..??

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rebuild your content permission in order to make it work. Sometimes the content permission it not functioning well. Go to the status report to see if there is any error msgs.